# Running sentiment analysis for facebook data in json format

Tags: python, json, facebook

I would first like to say that I am very new to coding and know the very basics at best

I was tasked with scraping data from facebook and running a sentiment analysis on it. I got the data using scraping-bot.io and I have it on a json file with the following format

```
{
    "owner_url": "https://www.facebook.com/########",
    "url": "https://www.facebook.com/post",
    "name": "Page name",
    "date": "date",
    "post_text": "Post title",
    "media_url": "media url attached",
    "likes": ###,
    "shares": ###,
    "num_comments": ###,
    "scrape_time": "date",
    "comments": [
      {
        "author_name": "Name",
        "text": "Comment text",
        "created": "Date"
      },
```

The posts are in spanish and so I looked up for a library to run the analysis with. I settled on https://pypi.org/project/sentiment-analysis-spanish/ (not sure if it's the best one, so I'm open to suggestions on that front as well)

Ideally I would like to be able to open the json file, run the sentiment analysis on "text" and then save that data into the same or a new file to visualize in another program.

This is what I have so far

```
from sentiment_analysis_spanish import sentiment_analysis
sentiment = sentiment_analysis.SentimentAnalysisSpanish()
 
f = open('C:/Users/vnare/Documents/WebScraping.json', encoding='utf-8-sig')
 
data = json.load(f)
 
for i in range(len('text')):
    print(sentiment.sentiment(i))
```

Currently it gives me the following error AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
But I'm sure there's far more that I'm doing wrong there.
I appreciate any help provided

Answer (score 0):

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower' means integer cannot be lower-cased. This means that somewhere in your code, you are trying to call the lower() string method on an integer.

If you take a look at the documentation for the sentiment analysis you provided, you will see that `print(sentiment.sentiment("something"))` will evaluate the sentiment of "something" and give you a score between 1 and 0.

My guess is that when you call `sentiment.sentiment("some text")` it will use `lower()` to convert whatever text is passed through to all lowercase. This would be fine if you were passing a string, but you are currently passing an integer!

By using `for i in range()`, you are indicating that you would like to take a range of numbers from 0 to the end number. This means that your i will always be an integer!

You need to instead loop through your JSON data to access the key/value pairs. "text" cannot be accessed directly as you've done above, but from within the JSON data, it can be!
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-with-python/

The important thing to look at is the format of the JSON data that you are trying to access. First, you need to access a dictionary key named "comments". However, what is inside of 'comments'?

`[{'author_name': 'Name', 'text': 'Comment text', 'created': 'Date'}]`

It's actually another dictionary of key-value pairs inside of a list. Given that list indices start at 0 and there is only one list element (the dictionary) in your example, we need to next use the index 0 to access the dictionary inside. Now, we will look for the key 'text' as you were initially.

When you are learning python, I highly recommend using a lot of print statements when trying to debug! This helps you see what your program sees so you know where the errors are.

```
import json
from sentiment_analysis_spanish import sentiment_analysis

sentiment = sentiment_analysis.SentimentAnalysisSpanish()

f = open('WebScraping.json', encoding='utf-8-sig')

data = json.load(f)
print(data)

comments = data['comments']
print(comments)

text = comments[0]['text']
print(text)

sentimentScore = sentiment.sentiment(text)
print(sentimentScore)
```

When you run this, the output will show you what is inside 'data', what is inside 'comments', what is inside 'text', and what the sentiment score is.

```py
{'owner_url': 'https://www.facebook.com/########', 'url': 'https://www.facebook.com/post', 'name': 'Page name', 'date': 'date', 'post_text': 'Post title', 'media_url': 'media url attached', 'likes': 234, 'shares': 500, 'num_comments': 100, 'scrape_time': 'date', 'comments': [{'author_name': 'Name', 'text': 'Comment text', 'created': 'Date'}]}

[{'author_name': 'Name', 'text': 'Comment text', 'created': 'Date'}]
Comment text

0.49789225920557484
```

This is what helped me see that inside of 'comments' was a dictionary within a list.

Now that you understand how it works, here is a more efficient way to run the code without all the extra prints! You can see I am now implementing the for loop you used earlier, as there may be multiple comments in a real-life scenario.

```py
import json
from sentiment_analysis_spanish import sentiment_analysis

sentiment = sentiment_analysis.SentimentAnalysisSpanish()

f = open('WebScraping.json', encoding='utf-8-sig')

data = json.load(f)
comments = data['comments']
i = 0

for i in range (len(comments)):
     comment = comments[i]['text']
     sentimentScore = sentiment.sentiment(comment)
     print(f"The sentiment score of this comment is {sentimentScore}.")
     print(f"The comment was: '{comment}'.")
```

This results in the following output.

```
The sentiment score of this comment is 0.49789225920557484.
The comment was: 'Comment 1'.
The sentiment score of this comment is 0.49789225920557484.
The comment was: 'Comment 2'.
```

This is the file that I used for reference.

```json
{
    "owner_url": "https://www.facebook.com/########",
    "url": "https://www.facebook.com/post",
    "name": "Page name",
    "date": "date",
    "post_text": "Post title",
    "media_url": "media url attached",
    "likes": 234,
    "shares": 500,
    "num_comments": 100,
    "scrape_time": "date",
    "comments": [
      {
        "author_name": "Name",
        "text": "Comment 1",
        "created": "Date"
      },
      {
        "author_name": "Name",
        "text": "Comment 2",
        "created": "Date"
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!. I tried your solution, however I ran into the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str". The "for i in range()" I had used earlier was actually a solution I found online for that error, but I still don't fully get why it works

Comment: No problem, happy to help figure this out with you! Could you paste the whole error here for me? My guess is that it's related to this part `text = dataType['comments']['text']` but I do want to be sure.

Comment: Actually, I see the problem! I have used your example JSON format above to test the code and found the solution that works. I will adjust my answer above with two examples - one that is a more efficient way and one that is less efficient but shows you why it works the way it does!